# Running a program using os.system in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run `Test.py` using `os.system(path)` where I specify the path of the file but I am getting an error. Basically, I want to run `Test.py` from here and display the output.

```
import os

os.system(rf"C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive-Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept15_2022\\220\\1\\Test.py")
```

The error is

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a python file, not an executable. You can pass `python yourfile.py`.

By the way, I would reconsider what you are doing, executing a python script from another python script is quite strange.

Comment: I want to execute multiple python scripts concurrently. I was thinking this would be a stepping stone. Is there a better way to do?

Comment: sure, import your python module and run the functions you need. To achieve parallelism there are several way, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html